# What is this UK coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, vector, utm, united-kingdom

I received a dataset of Merseyside area (corresponding to the metropolitan area of Liverpool, United Kingdom, broadly defined) where the location coordinates are totally a mystery to me, and unfortunately I'm unable to contact the corresponding analyst. Maybe some kind-hearted spirit can provide some help in identifying the coordinate system? I tried a standard UTM centred at N30 (it covers UK) but the resulting node ends up close to the centre of Africa.

I am enclosing some data to help the exploration:

```
LOCATION_EASTING LOCATION_NORTHING
335821 393051 
332930 414200 
340077 398681 
345144 389837 
353022 395484 
353022 395484 
335219 396507 
337123 394587 
334019 400474 
353022 395484 
353022 395484 
353022 395484 
352981 395138
```

Comment: This is a [useful website](https://gridreferencefinder.com/) if you are working on UK data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any data you receive from the UK with out a specified CRS will almost certainly be in OSGB ([EPSG:27700](https://epsg.io/27700)) which is the preferred CRS of our national mapping agency (OS).

Your data appears to be no exception:

[image]